# How do I find the most recent version of JavaFX to implement in my build.gradle file?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

What I believe is the official website, [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle), tells me to use version 0.0.10 in gradle. However, It's incompatible with JDK 8 and 17, spitting out `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`
I looked through the JavaFX repo, but couldnt find a good version number to replace 0.0.10 with, but I don't think 0.0.10 is really the most recent one. Where can I find the most recent build number?

Comment: See https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/.

Comment: Ensure that you are running the latest Gradle with the latest JDK - the error indicates that your JDK is outdated, meaning that if that message is printed, you cannot be running JDK 17.

Comment: AFAIK JavaFX 17 requieres JDK 11+. JavaFX was removed from Java JDK since JDK 11.

Comment: The latest version of the JavaFX **Gradle plugin** is 0.0.10. The plugin is a separate thing from JavaFX itself. The latest version of JavaFX is 17.0.1, as pointed out in the answer below. And as also pointed out, you need at least Java 11 to use JavaFX 11+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

Currently the latest versions for JavaFX development would be:

- **JavaFX Gradle Plugin 0.0.10** (simplifies working with JavaFX 11+ in Gradle projects)
- **OpenJFX 17.0.1** (libraries that implement JavaFX, require Java 11 or later)
- **Java 17.0.1** (an LTS version)

## *JavaFX Gradle Plugin*

[Comments by Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70145458/how-do-i-find-the-most-recent-version-of-javafx-to-implement-in-my-build-gradle/70146211#comment123999353_70145458) point out that you seem to be confusing the [Gradle plug-in for JavaFX](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-plugin?repo=gradle-plugins) with the [OpenJFX libraries](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx) needed to run a JavaFX app.

The plug-in simplifies working with JavaFX 11+ for [Gradle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) projects.

Currently, that plugin’s latest version is [0.0.10](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-plugin/0.0.10). See also the [GitHub product page](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin).

## *OpenJFX* libraries

As for the OpenJFX libraries, see the [Products Roadmap](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) at GluonHQ.com. You will find 17.0.1 is the latest, with 18 in early-access.

The JavaFX (OpenJFX) releases have been synced to arrive at about the same time as the Java releases, and use the same major version number. A convenient approach.

But OpenJFX releases do not require the latest Java. The [Release Notes for 17](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/doc-files/release-notes-17.md) says it requires Java 11 or later. Note that both Java 11 and 17 are [Long-Term Support (LTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) versions.

I suggest you generally do your development work with the latest Java and the latest JavaFX while aiming your deployments at the latest LTS version of both. Note that Oracle recently announced a change in the LTS cadence from every three years to every two years. Presumably JavaFX will follow that as well.

See also the related Question, [*Which version of OpenJFX (JavaFX) and Scene Builder should I use with Amazon Corretto 11 (OpenJDK)?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67910703/642706).

Comment: `0.0.10` is the latest version of the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` (i.e. the Gradle _plugin_). The OP likely got confused between the plugin and JavaFX itself.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for figuring out that confusion of products. I updated the Answer, and provided links.